# I changed the package name (because Google Play Store asked me to do so) and now app is not working?

Tags: android, package

The app was working fine, then Google Play Store asked me to change the package name in order to publish the new version as a new app. I did that, changed the package name everywhere. Now the app starts, this is how the splash image looks like:
[image]

Then the app stops, see image

[image]

After looking at the logcat I see that the old package name is still there (com.mind.creative.babyread). It looks like the old package name is still somewhere, but where and how do I change it? I did crt+shift+r and changed the package name but the old one still appears in the logcat. The new package name is (com.creativemind.newapp.babyread).

```
    2019-10-28 16:09:24.551 1787-1787/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@fd8eec5[Menu]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
2019-10-28 16:09:24.584 1787-1834/com.mind.creative.babyread D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x752f66a040, 0x752c27f000
2019-10-28 16:09:24.597 1787-1787/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@fd8eec5[Menu]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][720,1280] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
2019-10-28 16:09:24.619 1787-1787/com.mind.creative.babyread D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=69
2019-10-28 16:09:24.687 1787-1787/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@fd8eec5[Menu]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][720,1280] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x1 surface={valid=false 0} changed=false
2019-10-28 16:09:27.455 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread W/ResourceType: ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 3, previously 12
2019-10-28 16:09:27.475 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread W/ResourceType: ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 3, previously 12
2019-10-28 16:09:27.557 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread I/MediaPlayer: Need to enable context aware info
2019-10-28 16:09:27.557 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_setup
2019-10-28 16:09:27.557 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: constructor
2019-10-28 16:09:27.558 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: setListener
2019-10-28 16:09:27.563 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setVolume: left 1.000000  right 1.000000
2019-10-28 16:09:27.563 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: MediaPlayer::setVolume(1.000000, 1.000000)
2019-10-28 16:09:27.563 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setAuxEffectSendLevel: level 0.000000
2019-10-28 16:09:27.563 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: MediaPlayer::setAuxEffectSendLevel(0.000000)
2019-10-28 16:09:27.563 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setParameter: key 1400
2019-10-28 16:09:27.563 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: MediaPlayer::setParameter(1400)
2019-10-28 16:09:27.563 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setAudioStreamType: 3
2019-10-28 16:09:27.563 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
2019-10-28 16:09:27.563 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayer-JNI: set_session_id(): 5977
2019-10-28 16:09:27.563 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: MediaPlayer::setAudioSessionId(5977)
2019-10-28 16:09:27.563 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setDataSourceFD: fd 54
2019-10-28 16:09:27.563 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: setDataSource(54, 8699648, 435840)
2019-10-28 16:09:27.576 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: setVideoSurfaceTexture
2019-10-28 16:09:27.576 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: prepare
2019-10-28 16:09:27.591 2342-2364/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: message received msg=200, ext1=10973, ext2=0
2019-10-28 16:09:27.591 2342-2364/com.mind.creative.babyread W/MediaPlayerNative: info/warning (10973, 0)
2019-10-28 16:09:27.591 2342-2364/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: callback application
2019-10-28 16:09:27.591 2342-2364/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: back from callback
2019-10-28 16:09:27.592 2342-2364/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
2019-10-28 16:09:27.592 2342-2364/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: MediaPlayer::notify() prepared
2019-10-28 16:09:27.592 2342-2364/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: signal application thread
2019-10-28 16:09:27.592 2342-2364/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: callback application
2019-10-28 16:09:27.592 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: prepare complete - status=0
2019-10-28 16:09:27.592 2342-2364/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: back from callback
2019-10-28 16:09:27.598 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: invoke 68
2019-10-28 16:09:27.603 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread W/MediaPlayer: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
2019-10-28 16:09:27.604 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread W/MediaPlayer: See the documentation of setAudioStreamType() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
2019-10-28 16:09:27.605 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setVolume: left 1.000000  right 1.000000
2019-10-28 16:09:27.605 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: MediaPlayer::setVolume(1.000000, 1.000000)
2019-10-28 16:09:27.605 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setAuxEffectSendLevel: level 0.000000
2019-10-28 16:09:27.605 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: MediaPlayer::setAuxEffectSendLevel(0.000000)
2019-10-28 16:09:27.606 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setAudioStreamType: 3
2019-10-28 16:09:27.606 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
2019-10-28 16:09:27.606 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setLooping: 1
2019-10-28 16:09:27.606 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: MediaPlayer::setLooping
2019-10-28 16:09:27.606 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayer-JNI: start
2019-10-28 16:09:27.606 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: start
2019-10-28 16:09:27.648 2342-2383/com.mind.creative.babyread D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2019-10-28 16:09:27.657 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=61
2019-10-28 16:09:27.659 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@70dd3ae[Splash]: setView = DecorView@df6554f[Splash] TM=true MM=false
2019-10-28 16:09:27.661 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: invoke 68
2019-10-28 16:09:27.670 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@70dd3ae[Splash]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
2019-10-28 16:09:27.687 2342-2364/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: message received msg=6, ext1=0, ext2=0
2019-10-28 16:09:27.688 2342-2364/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: unrecognized message: (6, 0, 0)
2019-10-28 16:09:27.688 2342-2364/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: callback application
2019-10-28 16:09:27.688 2342-2364/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: back from callback
2019-10-28 16:09:27.699 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : true, logging : 0
2019-10-28 16:09:27.701 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@70dd3ae[Splash]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 503253458944} changed=true
2019-10-28 16:09:27.703 2342-2383/com.mind.creative.babyread I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 160a517, I47625b5b56
    Build Date                       : 06/13/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.22.00.01_06_07
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
2019-10-28 16:09:27.704 2342-2383/com.mind.creative.babyread D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2019-10-28 16:09:27.710 2342-2383/com.mind.creative.babyread I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff087, ME: 0x005ff063
2019-10-28 16:09:27.718 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@70dd3ae[Splash]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 720, 1280) ci=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) or=1
2019-10-28 16:09:27.718 2342-2383/com.mind.creative.babyread I/zygote64: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-10-28 16:09:27.718 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@70dd3ae[Splash]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
2019-10-28 16:09:27.719 2342-2383/com.mind.creative.babyread I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-10-28 16:09:27.719 2342-2383/com.mind.creative.babyread D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2019-10-28 16:09:27.721 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@80aa86 nm : com.mind.creative.babyread ic=null
2019-10-28 16:09:27.721 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2019-10-28 16:09:27.721 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2019-10-28 16:09:27.725 2342-2364/com.mind.creative.babyread D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=67
2019-10-28 16:09:27.726 2342-2383/com.mind.creative.babyread D/libGLESv1: STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package : com.mind.creative.babyread
2019-10-28 16:09:27.727 2342-2383/com.mind.creative.babyread D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x752f65ca40, 0x752c3e6010
2019-10-28 16:09:27.739 2342-2383/com.mind.creative.babyread D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2019-10-28 16:09:27.740 2342-2383/com.mind.creative.babyread D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2019-10-28 16:09:27.843 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 37 (msec)
2019-10-28 16:09:27.844 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@4619f47 nm : com.mind.creative.babyread ic=null
2019-10-28 16:09:27.844 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2019-10-28 16:09:34.534 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayer: resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
2019-10-28 16:09:34.535 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayer: cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
2019-10-28 16:09:34.535 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayer-JNI: release
2019-10-28 16:09:34.535 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: setListener
2019-10-28 16:09:34.535 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: disconnect
2019-10-28 16:09:34.587 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: destructor
2019-10-28 16:09:34.587 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/MediaPlayerNative: disconnect
2019-10-28 16:09:34.668 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=68
2019-10-28 16:09:34.670 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@fd8eec5[Menu]: setView = DecorView@97be01a[Menu] TM=true MM=false
2019-10-28 16:09:34.672 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@70dd3ae[Splash]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
2019-10-28 16:09:34.682 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/InputMethodManager: Not IME target window, ignoring
2019-10-28 16:09:34.683 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@fd8eec5[Menu]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
2019-10-28 16:09:34.703 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : true, logging : 0
2019-10-28 16:09:34.704 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@fd8eec5[Menu]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 503251976192} changed=true
2019-10-28 16:09:34.710 2342-2383/com.mind.creative.babyread D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x752f66a240, 0x752c27c010
2019-10-28 16:09:34.775 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f020003, entry index(3) is beyond type entryCount(3)
2019-10-28 16:09:34.834 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f020003, entry index(3) is beyond type entryCount(3)
2019-10-28 16:09:34.845 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f020004, entry index(4) is beyond type entryCount(3)
2019-10-28 16:09:34.861 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f020004, entry index(4) is beyond type entryCount(3)
2019-10-28 16:09:34.871 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f020005, entry index(5) is beyond type entryCount(3)
2019-10-28 16:09:35.233 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f020005, entry index(5) is beyond type entryCount(3)
2019-10-28 16:09:35.244 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f020006, entry index(6) is beyond type entryCount(3)
2019-10-28 16:09:35.275 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f020006, entry index(6) is beyond type entryCount(3)
2019-10-28 16:09:35.285 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f020007, entry index(7) is beyond type entryCount(3)
2019-10-28 16:09:35.300 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f020007, entry index(7) is beyond type entryCount(3)
2019-10-28 16:09:35.305 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/AbsListView:  in onLayout changed 
2019-10-28 16:09:35.309 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread I/Choreographer: Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2019-10-28 16:09:35.389 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@fd8eec5[Menu]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 720, 1280) ci=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) or=1
2019-10-28 16:09:35.390 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@fd8eec5[Menu]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
2019-10-28 16:09:35.403 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@16a85cc nm : com.mind.creative.babyread ic=null
2019-10-28 16:09:35.404 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2019-10-28 16:09:35.404 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2019-10-28 16:09:35.421 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=69
2019-10-28 16:09:35.422 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=67
2019-10-28 16:09:35.472 2342-2383/com.mind.creative.babyread D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x752f65ca40, 0x752c3e6000
2019-10-28 16:09:35.481 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@70dd3ae[Splash]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][720,1280] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
2019-10-28 16:09:35.833 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@70dd3ae[Splash]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
2019-10-28 16:09:35.833 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/InputEventReceiver: channel '1c4584a com.mind.creative.babyread/com.mind.creative.babyread.Splash (client)' ~ Disposing input event receiver.
2019-10-28 16:09:35.833 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/InputEventReceiver: channel '1c4584a com.mind.creative.babyread/com.mind.creative.babyread.Splash (client)' ~NativeInputEventReceiver.
2019-10-28 16:09:35.837 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=61
2019-10-28 16:10:14.000 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@fd8eec5[Menu]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
2019-10-28 16:10:14.029 2342-2383/com.mind.creative.babyread D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x752f66a240, 0x752c27c000
2019-10-28 16:10:14.046 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@fd8eec5[Menu]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][720,1280] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
2019-10-28 16:10:14.053 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=69
2019-10-28 16:10:14.112 2342-2342/com.mind.creative.babyread D/ViewRootImpl@fd8eec5[Menu]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][720,1280] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x1 surface={valid=false 0} changed=false
```

Comment: Did you try Ctrl + Shift + R and search for the old package name?

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot. I changed the package everywhere and the app is working, but if I look at the logcat I still see the old package see image. Anything else that I should do?

Comment: I would also follow the instructions as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio

Comment: Now after running the app I see the splash image, but then the app stops. In the logcat I still see the old package.

Comment: Did you change your package name in the manifest and build.gradle as well as do the refactor? If so you could File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart

Comment: I did invalidate cache and restart. I am having the same problem. When you say do the refactor, what do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201514/discussion-between-user3814312-and-koalakoalified).